# Процесс не выполняется

Tags: linux, django, процесс

На сервере запустил процесс, команду обработки django

```
./manage.py clear_duplicate_screenshots
```

Но она проработала 2 сек и приостановилась

```
ps -ax | grep manage
11845 pts/1    S+     0:02 python ./manage.py clear_duplicate_screenshots --dry-run
11893 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep manage
```

Как запустить ее, чтобы она не приостанавливалась и обработалась?

Comment: может он чего то ждет? к примеру, файловой системы

Comment: @KoVadim возможно. как проверить доступность файловой системы для процесса?

Comment: я не знаю, что делает скрипт, может он запустил другую программу и ждет, пока она завершится

Comment: @KoVadim скрипт берез из БД номера объектов и проверяет связанные с объектом изображения на наличие дубликатов

Comment: @KoVadim было бы "D".

Comment: проверил всё и остановился

Comment: @eri не вводите в заблужднение. за 3 дня скприт не выполнился, проработал 5 минут по данным из `ps`

Comment: @ZaArs 5 минут достаточно чтоб проверить милион дубликатов

Comment: каким образом?? я проверяю хеш всех файлов, в  бд нет поля хеша (вот думаю таки добавить, может ускорить процесс)